# How to know template name of an existing extension in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

If you have been provided a hybris extension code, how can we know it is generated using which template. For example, if I have been given an extension code, I want to know it is ycommercewebservice or ywebservice or yaccelatoraddon ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think this is not possible. A lot of extensions are not generated using a template at all (but just from scratch by manually creating the required files and directories), so I don't think it is noted anywhere during the creation process.